# Ansible nested loops, how to set inner loop variable based on outer variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2, nested-loops

I'm having problems with a nested loop on ansible.

I'm using ansible 2.5.2 with the following config files:

file **hosts**:

```
[group1]
host1
host2
host3
[group2]
hostA
```

file **host_vars/host{N}** (where N is the number for each host on group1):

```
variable:
  - { line: "keyB" , file: "keyc"}
  - { line: "key2" , file: "key3"}
```

I need to execute on hostA one task for each line in **host_vars/host{N}**.

in pseudo code, need something like this:

```
- name: modify file
  for host in groups['group1']:
    for item in host['variables']:
      lineinfile: "path={{ host }}/{{ item.file }} line={{ item.line }}"
```

using jinja2 loops does not work:

```
- name: Modify files
  lineinfile: "{% for linea in hostvars[item]['variables'] %}
              path={{ item }}/{{ linea.file }}
              line={{ linea.line }}
              {% endfor %}"
  loop: "{{ groups['group1'] }}"
```

normal nested loops does not work either because the inner loop deppends on the hostname:

```
- name: Modify files
  lineinfile: "path={{ item[0] }}/{{ item[1]['file'] }} line={{ item[1]['line'] }}"
  with_nested:
  - "{{ groups['group1'] }}"
  - "{{ hostvars[item[0]]['variables'] }}"
```

There is another way to cicle nested loops?

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem using loop_control,

I add a new file: **inner.yml**

```
- name: Modify files
  lineinfile: "path={{ outer_item }}/{{ item.file }} line={{ item.line }}"
  loop: "{{ hostvars[outer_item]['variables'] }}"
```

And defined my task file as follows

```
- include_tasks: inner.yml
  loop: "{{ groups['group1'] }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: outer_item
```

which solves my problem of using two nested variables on loops.